# Mistake using Bootstrap Tooltips, Working but with Bugs, I guess

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I want the tooltip to comes up when the 'focus' event happens.
When is focused doesn't come, after that comes like a :hover effect every time.
am I using jQuery in the right way to use the bootstrap tooltips?
Probably not right?

[image]
HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-toggle="estimate-tooltip-1" data-placement="top" title="How many are coming?" class="input-people amount-people-1" id="amount-people-1">
<input type="text" data-toggle="estimate-tooltip-2" data-placement="top" title="How many are coming?" class="input-people amount-people-2" id="amount-people-2">
```

Javascript jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var $firstEstimateInput = $('#amount-people-1');
  var $secondEstimateInput = $('#amount-people-2');


  $($firstEstimateInput).on('focus', function() {
      $('[data-toggle="estimate-tooltip-1"]').tooltip();
  });
  $($secondEstimateInput).on('focus', function() {
      $('[data-toggle="estimate-tooltip-2"]').tooltip();
  });


});
```

This is the Bootstrap javascript file Im calling:

```
 <script src="js/jquery-3.2.0.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="js/application.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance to all answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({"trigger":"focus"});
});
```

Please note, however, that I used the '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'. You can change this to:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('input').tooltip({"trigger":"focus"});
    });
```

...or whatever #selector (or .selector) you want.

Edit; https://jsfiddle.net/o4qt8ezd/

Comment: Felix Thanks a lot that's the right way.. tooltip({'trigger':'focus'});